# Can "eigenvalues" in eigenfunction expansion be non-scalar?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

This question is a bit nebulous but I don't have a particular example in mind... In general under certain assumptions, one can use eigenfunction expansion to represent an operator. For instance, for an operator $\mathcal{L}$
$$\mathcal{L} \psi_i = \lambda_i \cdot \psi_i \; ,$$ where $i = 1, \cdots, \infty$ for an orthonormal system $\psi_i$ dense in some space. Can $\lambda_i$ be a vector or matrix in such expansion, hence each $\psi_i$ is a vector or a matrix as well? I don't see a reason why it cannot be, if the operator $\mathcal{L}$ can be a map from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$. But if such scenario does exist, could you please point me to some reference using such expansion technique? If such scenario cannot exist, could you explain why?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $\mathcal L$ acts on functions $\Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^k$ then the functions $\psi_i$ themselves will be functions $\psi_i: \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R^k$.

Comment: The answer is simply no: eigenvalues are scalars by definition!

Comment: Thank you for your comments! But do you mean even the eigenfunctions could be multidimensional (when the underlying function map from $R^{k_1}$ to $R^{k_2}$, we still need scalar eigenvalues by definition?